# Unity Flappy bird Badges

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I have a question about if and else if. I want to set an image from the "medals" array based on the "score" variable:

```
if(score > 0)
{
    medals[0].SetActive(true);
}
else if
    (score > 2)
{
    medals[1].SetActive(true);
}
else if
   (score > 5)
{
    medals[2].SetActive(true);
}
```

It only shows one picture, the Bronze Medal medals[0]. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Sorry For Bad English
And Thanks for Advice

[Unity High_Score Badges C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38244923/unity-high-score-badges-c-sharp)

my updated code

```
score += Time.deltaTime;
            Scoretext.text = ((int)score).ToString();

            if (PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Highscore") < score)
                PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Highscore", score);

            if (score > 3)
            {
                bronze.GetComponent<Image>().enabled = true;
            }
            if
                (score > 7)
            {
                silver.GetComponent<Image>().enabled = true;
            }
            if
               (score > 13)
            {
                gold.GetComponent<Image>().enabled = true;
            }
```

Comment: Think about your logic for a moment. A score `>2` is obviously `>0`, so what do you think happens? Step through the code.

Comment: @MattBurland i used if and else if , it didnt work at all ,just only one image, but when i  change else if to if on everymethod it worked fine.

Comment: And why do you think that is? `if` vs `else if`? `else` only executes if the `if` evaluated to false.

Comment: [if-else (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h.aspx)

Comment: You need to learn to use your IDE's debugging tools to step through the code. You'll quickly gain an appreciation for the logic when you see it executing line by line.

Comment: @TimLehner Check my Previous post link is in Post, i want to just know if this isnt bad if i use If Statement without else thats all.

Comment: @mason Check my Previous post link is in Post, i want to just know if this isnt bad if i use If Statement without else thats all.

Comment: @PeterisUlmanis did you try that and step through it using the debugger? It's not "bad" if it's the logic you want and it's legal syntax.

Comment: Did anyone else read this question because of, "Flappy bird badges?"

Answer (score 0):

An 'else-if' statement will only be reached if the 'if' and 'else-if's above it are false.  In this case, any score > 0 will always stop at the first if statement, and never check the remaining else-ifs.

If your intention is to have all three badges show (one at score>0, the next at score>2, and the last at score>5), you could indeed use the code you suggested as a solution.

```
if(score > 0)
{
    medals[0].SetActive(true);
}
if (score > 2)
{
    medals[1].SetActive(true);
}
if
(score > 5)
{
    medals[2].SetActive(true);
}
```

This allows each 'if' statement to run regardless of the one before it.  Looking at the code you posted in the other question, it looks like this is in your Update loop, correct?  If so, this could be a better solution.  It only set's each medal active once.

```
if(score > 5 && !medals[2].activeInHierarchy)
{
    medals[2].SetActive(true);
}
else if (score > 2 && !medals[1].activeInHierarchy)
{
    medals[1].SetActive(true);
}
else if (score > 0 && !medals[0].activeInHierarchy)
{
    medals[0].SetActive(true);
}
```

While the 0 < score <= 2 it reaches the bottom else if and activates the first medal if it isn't already active.  Between 2 and 5, it activates the 2nd medal, and lastly a score>5 will activate the 3rd medal.

Comment: hello thanks for the script , i posted my script what i use now, with the if if if what i was talking about , can you help me with it?

Comment: i changed from medals[] to GetComponent Images, and it it all if if if and dont know if this ir properly working, i edit my post and putted 2 codes so please help out

Comment: Have you tried running your project to see if it is working properly?

Comment: Jup ,it changes images as good as i need, but i dont know if i did this correctly. But it works. :D